# Android: G+ login and get details

Tags: android, google-plus

I am doing a module where i need to make user login through google plus.
I can get name and email of user but struck with getting list of people in his/her circle.
Does any one know how to get list of people in the person circles.??

Here is my code .Some what lengthy..

```
public class SignIn extends Activity implements ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>,ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener ,OnClickListener
{
    //declaration of variables  

        static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = 
            "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin_layout);


        //googleapiclient initialization..
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
        initializecontrols();
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                String em=email.getText().toString();
                String ps=pswd.getText().toString();
                if(em.length()==0||ps.length()==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter all the above", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(validate(em))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong email format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        fb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yet to do..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        gp.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public boolean validate(final String hex) 
    {

        matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
        return matcher.matches();

    }
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
          if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
            // 'sign-in'.
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
              // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
              // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
              resolveSignInError();
            }
          }
        }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.gplogin && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())
        {
             mSignInClicked = true;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
//      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getProfileInformation();
        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
          .setResultCallback(this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
            Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

      }
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) 
            {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String nickname = currentPerson.getNickname();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
                Log.e("Output :", "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Name : "+personName+"\n Email :"+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) 
    {
        Log.e("function","onResult");
         if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
                try {
                  int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Log.d("Person", "Display name: " + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                  }
                } finally {
                  personBuffer.close();
                }
              } else {
                Log.e("person", "Error requesting visible circles: " + peopleData.getStatus());
              }
    }

}
```

---

According to the tutorial onResult callback method will be called when

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
          .setResultCallback(this);
```

this particular code is executed in OnConnected method

Comment: Show what you have and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have added the code i am workin..

Comment: And what is the problem that you face when you use `Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(...)` ?

Comment: plus.people.loadVisible().. will call the onResult method according to tutorial..https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people..But it was not getting called.

Comment: Please prepare a short extract of the code that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are disconnecting immediately after you make the request.

Google Play services uses a client-service architecture with asynchronous callbacks.  Disconnecting actually closes the service connection, preventing the response from being delivered back to you.  This is akin to calling up your buddy, saying "hey, how's it going" and then immediately hanging up your phone.

As an aside, there are a couple other non-standard things going on here.  In general you should call connect in onStart() (you have this commented out).  If the user has already given your app permission then you can immediately start getting data and doing what you want with it.  If the user hasn't granted permission or there's another issue (like it's a Kindle Fire, where Google Play services isn't available), then you'll get onConnectionFailed.  You can then hold on to that Status and call the resolution when the user clicks on the button.  This will result in a snappier UI and make it easier for you to match your connect() and disconnect() calls.

In general disconnect() should be called in onStop().  This way you won't disconnect until your activity is being torn down anyway.